# linking fusion tables visualizations, offering search over fusiontables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

So I've got a couple of different fusiontable visualizations in a google site:

https://sites.google.com/site/hlsbeta123123123123/

I am wondering if there is a way to link them so that when a pin in the map is selected the corresponding card is shown in the other iframe?

What I'd really like to be able to do is offer people a search over the fusion table via the google site, so that when somebody searched in the site search, they'd get back a list of hits in the map and cards, and have them all linked up together ...  Any simple way to do this over paired visualizations or would this have to be custom site built on the fusiontables API?

I know fusion tables wizard:

http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html

can provide something like this for a single visualization, but am unclear about linking multiple visualizations - maybe that's just completely impractical ...

Many thanks in advance
Cheers> SAM

p.s. Here's a current screenshot in case it the site changes :-)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but instead of the iframe-map you must create the map on your own to be able to modify the default behaviour(opening of the infoWindow on click and load the filtered card instead).

It's not much difficult, the most of the src you will get with `map->publish->get HTML and javascript`

All you have to do is:

1. supress the infoWindows(set the `suppressInfoWindows`-option of the layer to true)
2. observe the click-event of the layer and load the card based on a unique col(`Charity Number` appears to be unique)

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(layerl0, 'click',function(e){
       document.getElementById('cards')//iframe-element
        .src='https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=CARD&q=select+*+from+1ZnLJPfdXgiD49s3JO9Vyhf0VPGgBnzs-985jT3s+where+col1+%3D+'+e.row['Charity Number'].value+'&tmplt=4&cpr=1';
      });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/YVnus/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/YVnus/)

But actually showing the cards in an iframe forces a redundant request, instead you may fetch the contents of the infoWindow and insert them directly into the page.

Comment: thanks - that's really useful.  I used the Google fusion wizard to make a version with search: https://sites.google.com/site/hlsbeta123123123123/search-by-activity guess I need to post that broader joined search question separately ... wonder if I can highlight just the selected card in the list of cards, but keep the list available? lots of fun to have here - will check doc on suppressInfoWindows ...

Comment: Highlightning of a card will not be possible, you will need script-access to the cards to achieve it, but script-access is not possible because of same-origin-restrictions. But it will be possible to keep the complete list available and scroll the selected card into view. Therefore you must edit the cards-template and create a anchor for each card. Load the URL with the related hash into the frame when you click on a marker.